Archive times for a Mac Catalyst app suddenly jumped from 1 minute to 60 with Xcode 16
Regular builds are exactly the same as before, but since I updated to Xcode 16 my archive time has gone up to over an hour. It seems to get stuck on compiling swift source files, but it lumps them all together in the output so I don't know which one is causing the issue. Anyone got any suggestions for fixing this?

I found out that the compiler was unhappy with me PaintCode swift file that drew all my custom buttons. Exactly the same files are used in my iOS apps and archive causes no problem, but Xcode 16 was choking on this file only on Mac Catalyst, and only when I archived, not building locally. I just had to find an alternative way of drawing my buttons. Clearly a bug.
